# How do Powershell commands work?

Tags: windows, powershell

Is it possible to find the files related to specific commands or config files?
For example I want to know the full detail of what happens when I type a command such 'add-appxPackage'?
I know what is required for it, but I want to know the coding behind it

Comment: "find the files related to specific commands or config files", I'm not sure what you're looking for here.  Can you explain or give an example?  What kind of "files" are you expecting to find?  "I want to know the coding behind it"  What do you mean by this?  You want to see the source code for the commandlet itself?  Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/266250/can-we-see-the-source-code-for-powershell-cmdlets) the info you're looking for?

Comment: How does it execute there must b some dll or something with the instructions, of everything that happens behind the screen?

Comment: Chances are that PowerShell functions are using DLL functions exported by standard Windows libraries.

Comment: Unfortunately, Windows is not Open Source. Decompilers, even for .NET, are also useless for anything but basic code.

Answer (score 4):

For compiled Cmdlets, you can get the path to the `.dll` with:

```
(Get-Command Get-ChildItem).DLL
```

(Replace `Get-ChildItem` with the cmdlet you are interested in)

Once you know the path to the `.dll`, you can open it with a .NET disassembler like [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/):

```
& dotPeek64.exe (Get-Command Get-ChildItem).DLL
```

[Source of above answer (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32189485/225906)

Example:

Running `(get-command add-appxPackage).dll` on my system returns:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands\v4.0_6.3.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.dll`

For more info check out this entire StackOverflow Q&A:

[Can we see the source code for PowerShell cmdlets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266250/can-we-see-the-source-code-for-powershell-cmdlets)

Comment: As an alternative, you could probably watch a PowerShell script using an API watcher, such as "API Monitor" by rohitab (I have never actually used it, so I make no statement of its effectiveness or safety).